# Test angularjs module when config is in module.constant. angular.mock

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I am testing my angularJS application. While testing routes, I am using **angular.mock.module('module1')** to mock a parent route and later used for testing child routes.

The official definition of angular.mock.module() says  - *This function registers a module configuration code. It collects the configuration information which will be used when the injector is created by inject*.

The problem is that I have defined the module config in .constant instead of .config. I had to do this to register state dynamically at application bootstrap.

I want to mock the module using the configuration stored in the .constant object.

`angular.module('name', []`

`.constant('cons', { name: 'name', url: 'url', views: {}})`